# Using a static method instead of a factory using json_serializable

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serialization

Is there a reason why using json_serializable I should use a factory constructor instead of a static method?

I would need to use a static method, but I'm wondering about the downsides

Comment: I read somewhere (can't find the source now) that a factory constructor is essentially a static method that returns a new instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Using `factory` has a purpose here:

it forces you to define

`factory` counts as a constructor, so if you define at least one then there's no implicit constructor:

```dart
class Foo {
  factory Foo.fromJson() {
    return Foo(); // Doesn't compile
  }
}
```

Which is opposed to:

```dart
class Foo {
  static Foo.fromJson() {
    return Foo(); // compiles
  }
}
```